# Seaborn FacetGrid cutting off charts

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, seaborn, facet-grid

I have some data I want to visualize in a Seaborn `FacetGrid`.

```
half_counts = all_counts.loc[all_counts['location_id'] <= 50]
g = sns.FacetGrid(half_counts, col="location_id", col_wrap=10)
g = g.map(sns.pointplot, "invite_sent_time", "q_i_ratio", scale=.7)
```

However, the resulting plots are cut off:

[image]
How do I fix this?

Comment: It looks like `invite_sent_time` is a timestamp and it is shrinking the axes to fit the very large labels. I think you probably don't want to use `sns.pointplot` here since timestamps are usually not categorical.

Comment: Do you recommend using something else? I was able to get this to work relatively easy in ggplot, but curious if I can make it work in Seaborn as well.

Comment: startwith  `g = g.map(plt.scatter, "invite_sent_time", "q_i_ratio")` where `plt` comes from `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`